# How do I read data from a .txt file and convert the data into a integer?

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, integer

I am coding a distance sensor to read data from a raspberry Pi to a website. The data must read into a .txt file and then be transferred from the .txt file onto a website. I need help understanding how to convert the data in the .txt file from a string into an integer to allow me to change the font color based on the numerical value of the data.

I have tried multiple methods such as attempting to use the Number() method but I could not figure it out.

```
<iframe id="textfile" src="SensorData.txt"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
Number(SensorData.txt);
function print() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('textfile');
iframe.contentWindow.print();
if(iframe<200){
str.fontcolor("red");
} else {
str.fontcolor("green");
}
}
</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT=".5">
```

The results should show the data on an html file constantly refreshing and changing color from red to green based on the distance calculated.

Comment: For converting string to int there is a function parseInt. Is that what you are looking for? [link]https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result to be constantly refreshing, you can use a `fetch` statement to read the text file, and running it every x milliseconds using `setInterval()`.

For the integer conversion part, `parseInt()` should do the trick.

```
function print() {
  fetch("yourFile.txt")
    .then(function(response) { return response.text; })
    .then(function(text) {
      var num = parseInt(text);
      //do the red/green coloring using num
    });
}
setInterval(print, 1000); //run function print() every 1 second
```